# Difference between mkfifo() and mknod()

Tags: c, linux, pipe, mkfifo

What is the difference between mkfifo() and mknod() while creating a named pipe?

I tried searching but couldn't get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using [`mkfifo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkfifo.html) is standardized and portable.  Using [`mknod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mknod.html) in general, is not portable — it is a part of POSIX (despite a statement to the contrary in an earlier version of this answer).  The POSIX specification says that `mkfifo()` should be preferred.  Otherwise, there is no difference between a FIFO created by `mkfifo()` and `mknod()`.

Note that `mknod()` can be used to create other device types than just FIFOs.  It can create block special and character special devices.  Once upon a very (very, very) long time ago, `mknod()` was used to create directories too — in the days before there was a `mkdir()` or `rmdir()` system call. After creating the directory, you had to use `link()` twice to create the `.` and `..` entries in the new directory.  (And you had to have root privileges to use it, so the `mkdir` and `rmdir` commands were SUID root.)  File systems are a lot more reliable nowadays because that's no longer part of the game.

Reference: [Version 7 Unix](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/) — circa 1979.

Comment: Uhm, my `mknod` manpage says «POSIX.1-2001 says: "The only portable use of `mknod()` is to create a FIFO-special file. If `mode` is not `S_IFIFO` or `dev` is not `0`, the behavior of `mknod()` is unspecified."», so it seems that `mknod` with `S_IFIFO` *is* indeed standard. This is confirmed by http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mknod.html, with the caveat that "The `mkfifo()` function is preferred over this function for making FIFO special files."

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Oh — hmm, thanks.  You're correct that `mknod()` is in POSIX — much to my surprise.  Given the existence of `mkfifo()` (and `mkdir()` and `rmdir()`), the function is really superfluous; I'm surprised that it is standardized.  It's curious that the function is illustrated in the spec with an uninitialized value for the third argument: `dev_t dev;
int   status = mknod("/home/cnd/mod_done", S_IFIFO | S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH, dev);` — `dev` is not shown as initialized.  Setting it to 0 would be sane; there was verbiage in the 7th Edition manual suggesting that.